# sequences convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence of real numbers. Prove that $x_n \to x$ if and only if
$$x = x_1 + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(x_{k+1} - x_k)$$
I have initially tried solving by expanding the bottom part all the terms in the sigma expansion gets cancelled and we are left out with a single term, How to show the convergence criteria.Should I prove its cauchy sequence or any other approach?

Comment: You are more or less finished as $x_1 + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(x_{k+1} - x_k) = x_n  - x_1 + x_1 = x_n$. So the limit of partial sums is the limit of the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

If $x_n\rightarrow x$. Let $y_n=x_1+\sum_1^n (x_{k+1}-x_k)=x_{n+1}\rightarrow x$. So the underlying infinite series converges to $x$ and conversely...

Comment: In the telescoping sum, the first term is $x_2 - x_1 = 2 -1 = 1 \neq 0$

Comment: Ohhhh yes ...will work out then